# Universal Date Converter library in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My Cocoa app works with it's own database and allows user to import some csv files. So I have to parse strings from CSV to proper Core Data data types. The problem is in date parsing because I don't know which date format will be used in user's DB and telling user which format to use looks some like not too user-friendly. 
Do I have to do it in a "hard-way" using switch-control or maybe NSDate has some cool stuff to deal with it?
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know the user's input format then how can "some cool stuff" figure out if – for example –  "04/01/2015" is January 4th or April 1st?

Comment: @MartinR exactly, no magic to expect from NSDate. That means I have to go through all the possible variants of date formats?

Comment: Even then, how would you determine the correct interpretation of "04/01/2015" if you have *no information* about the format?

Comment: @MartinR obviously, data misrepresentation. My desire to make super easy import tool seems to be impossible

Comment: I would think the only way to do it would be to hold off converting the dates until you see a date component above 12 (in which case you may assume that field is the day and the other is the month). What you do if no such dates are in the CSV file is up to you - you could ask the user, or use the user's locale...